# "Submit" Button requires two clicks to submit React Js

Tags: reactjs

So I wanted to add "whatsapp" like voice note feature in my app I am working on, where you record the voice note and click the "Send" button to send it. I have added the voice recorder code and its working fine in my Logs, but the problem is that when I press the "Send recording" button it sends an empty file in the chat box, and on pressing the same button the second time it then actually sends the recorded Voice note.

**The Recorder code component "useRecorder"**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Conversation_Logs from "../Logs/Conversation_Logs";

const useRecorder = () => {

  
  const [audioURL, setAudioURL] = useState("");
  const [audioBlob, setAudioBlob] = useState("");
  const [isRecording, setIsRecording] = useState(false);
  const [recorder, setRecorder] = useState(null);


  useEffect(() => {
    // Lazily obtain recorder first time we're recording.
    if (recorder === null) {
      if (isRecording) {
        requestRecorder().then(setRecorder, console.error);
      }
      return;
    }

    // Manage recorder state.
    if (isRecording) {
      recorder.start();
    } else {
      recorder.stop();
    }

    // Obtain the audio when ready.
    const handleData = e => {
      setAudioURL(URL.createObjectURL(e.data));
      
      let wavfromblob = new File([e.data], "incomingaudioclip.wav")

      setAudioBlob(wavfromblob);

    };

    recorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", handleData);
    return () => recorder.removeEventListener("dataavailable", handleData);
  }, [recorder, isRecording]);

  const startRecording = () => {
    setIsRecording(true);
  };

  const stopRecording = () => {
    setIsRecording(false);
    
  };

  return [audioURL,audioBlob, isRecording, startRecording, stopRecording];
};

async function requestRecorder() {
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
  return new MediaRecorder(stream);
}
export default useRecorder;
```

**The Code where send recording button is called component named "RecorderBox**

```
import  React, {useState,useEffect} from "react";

import { render } from "react-dom";
import useRecorder from "./useRecorder";

const RecorderBox = (props) =>{


  const { log, handleUpdateLog,handleSubmitNewMessage ,selectedLog} = props

  
   let [audioURL,audioBlob, isRecording, startRecording, stopRecording] = useRecorder();

   const [ newMessage, setNewMessage ] = useState("");
   const [ attachFile, setAttachFile ] = useState();
   
   
  
      const submitNewMessage = () => {
      
      
      setAttachFile(audioBlob)
        
        const body = {
            body: newMessage,
            attachment: attachFile
            
        }
        handleUpdateLog(log,newMessage, attachFile) 
        console.log(attachFile)
        // handleSubmitNewMessage(log.id,body)
    }
   
 

   useEffect(() => {
        setNewMessage("")
        setAttachFile(null)
              
        !!document.getElementsByClassName("dzu-previewButton")[0] && document.getElementsByClassName("dzu-previewButton")[0].click()
    }, [log])
  return (
    <div className="RecorderBox">
      <audio src={audioURL} controls />
      <button onClick={startRecording} disabled={isRecording}>
        start recording
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => {
        stopRecording();
          
        }} disabled={!isRecording}>
        stop recording
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => {
       
          submitNewMessage();
         
          
        }}>
          
        send recording
      </button>

      <p>
        <em>
          
        </em>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default RecorderBox;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR: `submitNewMessage` is running in the scope of the previous render,** thus `attachFile` doesn't contain anything yet. Whatever audio you managed to send on the second click was actually **the first** recording you tried to send.

**Solution:** Skip `attachFile` completely.

A couple of hints: Don't have a `useEffect` depend on a state that the effect itself is updating, and dont use a `useEffect` for doing something that a click-handler can do.

Here's a safer version of your code. **I haven't tested it,** but any bugs should be easy to fix.

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

// This is a nugget I use in many similar cases.
/**
 * Similar to `useMemo`, but accepts a callback that return a promise.
 * Very useful when working with states that depend on some async function.
 * 
 * @link https://gist.github.com/mariusbrataas/ffca05c210ec540b4fb9f4324c4f2e68
 *
 * @example
 * function MyComponent({url}:{url: string}) {
 *   const data = usePromiseMemo(
 *     () => 
 *       fetch(url)
 *         .then(r => r.json())
 *         .then(r => r.my.user.info),
 *     [url]
 *   );
 * 
 *   return <p>{info || "Loading info..."}</p>
 * }
 */
export function usePromiseMemo<T>(
  callback: () => Promise<T> | T,
  deps?: any[]
) {
  // Private states
  const [state, setState] = useState<T>();
  const isMounted = useRef(true);

  // Register unmount
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isMounted.current) isMounted.current = true;
    return () => {
      isMounted.current = false;
    };
  }, []);

  // Execute callback
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isMounted.current) {
      if (state !== undefined) setState(undefined);
      Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => callback())
        .then(r => {
          if (isMounted.current) setState(r);
        });
    }
  }, deps || []);

  // Return state
  return state;
}

function useRecorder() {
  const [audioURL, setAudioURL] = useState<string>();
  const [audioBlob, setAudioBlob] = useState<File>();
  const [isRecording, setIsRecording] = useState(false);

  // Handler for recorded data
  const handleRecorderData = useCallback(
    (e: BlobEvent) => {
      setAudioURL(URL.createObjectURL(e.data));
      setAudioBlob(new File([e.data], 'incomingaudioclip.wav'));
    },
    [setAudioURL, setAudioBlob]
  );

  // Create recorder
  const recorder = usePromiseMemo(
    () =>
      navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({ audio: true })
        .then(stream => new MediaRecorder(stream)),
    []
  );

  // Attach event listener
  useEffect(() => {
    if (recorder)
      recorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', handleRecorderData);
    return () => {
      if (recorder)
        recorder.removeEventListener('dataavailable', handleRecorderData);
    };
  }, [recorder, handleRecorderData]);

  // Handle start recording
  const startRecording = useCallback(() => {
    if (recorder) {
      recorder.start();
      setIsRecording(true);
    }
  }, [recorder, setIsRecording]);

  // Handle stop recording
  const stopRecording = useCallback(() => {
    if (recorder) {
      recorder.stop();
      setIsRecording(false);
    }
  }, [recorder, setIsRecording]);

  // Return
  return {
    audioURL,
    audioBlob,
    setAudioBlob,
    isRecording,
    startRecording,
    stopRecording
  };
}

export const RecorderBox = ({
  log,
  handleUpdateLog,
  handleSubmitNewMessage,
  selectedLog
}: any) => {
  const {
    audioURL,
    audioBlob,
    setAudioBlob,
    isRecording,
    startRecording,
    stopRecording
  } = useRecorder();

  const [newMessage, setNewMessage] = useState('');

  // Create a decorated submit function
  const decoratedSubmitNewMessage = useCallback(() => {
    const body = {
      body: newMessage,
      attachment: audioBlob
    };
    handleUpdateLog(log, newMessage, audioBlob);
    // handleSubmitNewMessage(log.id, body); // You had this commented out, but it should work just fine.
  }, [handleUpdateLog, handleSubmitNewMessage, audioBlob, newMessage]);

  // Cleanup whenever receiving new object for `log`
  useEffect(() => {
    setNewMessage('');
    setAudioBlob(undefined);
    document.getElementsByClassName('dzu-previewButton')[0]?.click(); // No idea what this is supposed to do.
  }, [log, setNewMessage, setAudioBlob]);

  return (
    <div className="RecorderBox">
      <audio src={audioURL} controls />
      <button onClick={startRecording} disabled={isRecording}>
        start recording
      </button>
      <button onClick={stopRecording} disabled={!isRecording}>
        stop recording
      </button>
      <button onClick={decoratedSubmitNewMessage}>send recording</button>
      <p>
        <em></em>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**JavaScript version:**

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

// This is a nugget I use in many similar cases.
/**
 * Similar to `useMemo`, but accepts a callback that return a promise.
 * Very useful when working with states that depend on some async function.
 *
 * @link https://gist.github.com/mariusbrataas/ffca05c210ec540b4fb9f4324c4f2e68
 *
 * @example
 * function MyComponent({url}:{url: string}) {
 *   const data = usePromiseMemo(
 *     () =>
 *       fetch(url)
 *         .then(r => r.json())
 *         .then(r => r.my.user.info),
 *     [url]
 *   );
 *
 *   return <p>{info || "Loading info..."}</p>
 * }
 */
export function usePromiseMemo(callback, deps) {
  // Private states
  const [state, setState] = useState();
  const isMounted = useRef(true);

  // Register unmount
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isMounted.current) isMounted.current = true;
    return () => {
      isMounted.current = false;
    };
  }, []);

  // Execute callback
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isMounted.current) {
      if (state !== undefined) setState(undefined);
      Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => callback())
        .then(r => {
          if (isMounted.current) setState(r);
        });
    }
  }, deps || []);

  // Return state
  return state;
}

function useRecorder() {
  const [audioURL, setAudioURL] = useState();
  const [audioBlob, setAudioBlob] = useState();
  const [isRecording, setIsRecording] = useState(false);

  // Handler for recorded data
  const handleRecorderData = useCallback(
    e => {
      setAudioURL(URL.createObjectURL(e.data));
      setAudioBlob(new File([e.data], 'incomingaudioclip.wav'));
    },
    [setAudioURL, setAudioBlob]
  );

  // Create recorder
  const recorder = usePromiseMemo(
    () =>
      navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({ audio: true })
        .then(stream => new MediaRecorder(stream)),
    []
  );

  // Attach event listener
  useEffect(() => {
    if (recorder)
      recorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', handleRecorderData);
    return () => {
      if (recorder)
        recorder.removeEventListener('dataavailable', handleRecorderData);
    };
  }, [recorder, handleRecorderData]);

  // Handle start recording
  const startRecording = useCallback(() => {
    if (recorder) {
      recorder.start();
      setIsRecording(true);
    }
  }, [recorder, setIsRecording]);

  // Handle stop recording
  const stopRecording = useCallback(() => {
    if (recorder) {
      recorder.stop();
      setIsRecording(false);
    }
  }, [recorder, setIsRecording]);

  // Return
  return {
    audioURL,
    audioBlob,
    setAudioBlob,
    isRecording,
    startRecording,
    stopRecording
  };
}

export const RecorderBox = ({
  log,
  handleUpdateLog,
  handleSubmitNewMessage,
  selectedLog
}) => {
  const {
    audioURL,
    audioBlob,
    setAudioBlob,
    isRecording,
    startRecording,
    stopRecording
  } = useRecorder();

  const [newMessage, setNewMessage] = useState('');

  // Create a decorated submit function
  const decoratedSubmitNewMessage = useCallback(() => {
    const body = {
      body: newMessage,
      attachment: audioBlob
    };
    handleUpdateLog(log, newMessage, audioBlob);
    // handleSubmitNewMessage(log.id, body); // You had this commented out, but it should work just fine.
  }, [handleUpdateLog, handleSubmitNewMessage, audioBlob, newMessage]);

  // Cleanup whenever receiving new object for `log`
  useEffect(() => {
    setNewMessage('');
    setAudioBlob(undefined);
    document.getElementsByClassName('dzu-previewButton')[0]?.click(); // No idea what this is supposed to do.
  }, [log, setNewMessage, setAudioBlob]);

  return (
    <div className="RecorderBox">
      <audio src={audioURL} controls />
      <button onClick={startRecording} disabled={isRecording}>
        start recording
      </button>
      <button onClick={stopRecording} disabled={!isRecording}>
        stop recording
      </button>
      <button onClick={decoratedSubmitNewMessage}>send recording</button>
      <p>
        <em></em>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you provide the bug fixed version of this code, since I am getting "Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files." error. Thank You!

Comment: You could simply remove anything that isn't JavaScript, but in general I'd recommend using TypeScript. Adding JS version now tho

Comment: Hi, I have used the Javascript code but on compiling it gives "./src/components/Recorder/useRecorder.jsx
  Line 72:27:  'newMediaRecorder' is not defined  no-undef" error. Thanks

Comment: **You are not running the code I suggested above.** `newMediaRecorder` does not exist in there. I just tested the code, and it works just fine:) Have a look here: https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-danilo-d1nne?file=/src/App.js